# laravel 6 upload image error

Tags: php, laravel, fileupload

при загрузке картинку не загрузит дает такой ерор
The file "en.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

```
foreach ($request->file('photo') as $photo){
    $time = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $imageName = time().'.'.$photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $photo->move(public_path('campaigns/larges'), $imageName);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй вместо move метод storeAs. Документация:  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Например как-то так:

```
foreach ($request->file('photo') as $photo){
    $time = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $imageName = time().'.'.$photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $photo->storeAs('campaigns/larges', $imageName, 'public');
}
```

Если вам не принципиально важно использовать в качестве имени файла дату, рекомендую использовать store. Этот метод автоматически сгенерирует имя файла в виде хэша и вернет его.

Не забудьте опубликовать ссылку на хранилище, если не делали этого ранее, для отображения файлов по http, если это требуется

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Спасибо большое